# Можно ли настроить NSLayoutConstraint относительно UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Надо с помощью `NSLayoutConstraint` настроить размещение `testView` на фиксированном расстоянии под `UINavigationBar`. Проблема в том, что высота `UINavigationBar` изменяется при вращении экрана.

Как настроить сonstraint-ы под изменение высоты `UINavigationBar`?

см. блок "// Y" в примере кода

```
self.testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[self.testView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addSubview:self.testView];
// Width
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.testView
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:nil
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                multiplier:0
                                                  constant:100]];
// Height
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.testView
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:nil
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                multiplier:1
                                                  constant:100]];
// Y
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.testView
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:self.topLayoutGuide
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                  constant:70.f]];    
// X
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.testView
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:self.view
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                  constant:0.0]];
```

Результат сейчас выглядит так:

[image: горизонтально]
[image: вертикально]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно посмотреть на [topLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/topLayoutGuide) и использовать не `Top` атрибут, а `Bottom`.

Так же рекомендуется использовать новое API - `NSLayoutAnchor`

```
    let redView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 50)))
    redView.backgroundColor = .redColor()
    redView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(redView)

    redView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.centerXAnchor).active = true
    redView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 16).active = true

    redView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(50).active = true
    redView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(100).active = true
```

Comment: пример кода был под `swift`, но совет помог, спасибо.                                   
`attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom`